# libuv vs. raw epoll or IOCP

Tags: multithreading, epoll, iocp, libuv

I'm writing the IO core for a messaging library and considering libuv vs. using raw epoll on linux and IOCP on windows (and eventually others, solaris events etc.) I like the portability of libuv, I'm looking at the performance.

epoll and IOCP allow multiple threads to wait directly for IO events, the kernel does the dispatching. Potentially more efficient than user-space dispatching though I don't have any numbers.

libuv (based on my reading) has a thread-usafe event loop, but I could implement a leader-follower thread pool. By that I mean one thread (at a time) is the "leader" waiting for events. When the leader gets an event it signals that a follower should take over as leader. The ex-leader process the event and then becomes a follower.

My hope is that should be close in performance to raw multi-threaded epoll/IOCP, assuming libuv is efficiently implemented. I will do my own measurements, but I'd like to hear from anyone with experience.

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: I'm one of the maintainers of libuv.

I'd advise you start with libuv. If only because it contains hunderds of corner cases already taken care of, and tons of knowledge built in. If you want to support other platforms you are going to end up reinventing libuv one way or another :-)

Once you have built your server prototype with libuv run some benchmarks and see where the bottleneck is. Depending on the type of server you are writing you may need / want a multi-threaded event loop, which libuv isn't, but chances are libuv will work fine enough for you.

Comment: The server is built, I have to make it faster. Multi-threading is not optional, we need to scale on multi-core machines. Ideally I'd like a portable multi-threaded poller that can serialize activity per-connection (like epoll) However I think that a single-threaded libuv event loop run in leader-follower style could do the trick - all the application work can be concurrent per-connection, only fairly lightweight buffer-handover for async read/write will get serialized thru libuv. At least that's what I'm hoping :)

Comment: You can take the following approach: have one loop per thread, with one "main" thread which handles incoming connections and dispatches them to the "worker" threads using `uv_write2` in a round-robin fashion. So each worker would handle 1/N th of the connections.

Comment: Is there a document covering trade-offs explicitly?